# addEventListener on click, choose not `this`

Tags: javascript

I have a loop with addEventListener function:

```
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');

for (var t = 0; t < tabs.length; t++) {
  tabs[t].addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.className += ' active';
  }, false);
}
```

As you can see, I want to add `.active` class name to my `li` on click event.
But also, I want to remove `.active` class, from my others `li`'s. How can I do this trick?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/AleshaOleg/er825dch) is a example.

```js
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');

for (var t = 0; t < tabs.length; t++) {
  tabs[t].addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.className += ' active';
  }, false);
}
```

```css
.tabs {
  display: inline-block;
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    li {
      cursor: pointer;
      float: left;
      padding: 10px 40px;
      background: #FDFDFD;
      &.active {
        background: #8F95B0;
        color: #FFF;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li class="tab active">Product Overview</li>
    <li class="tab">Specifications</li>
    <li class="tab">Related products</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: do u have to only javascript. This would be much easy with jQuery with lesser lines of code.

Comment: @Manish i know, interested in pure js decision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove *`active`* class from all the elements first,

```
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');

for (var t = 0; t < tabs.length; t++){
  tabs[t].addEventListener('click', function(){
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    //select all the elements with class active
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".active")).forEach(function(itm){
        itm.classList.remove("active")
    });
    //And remove the class active from it.
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    this.classList.add('active');
  }, false);
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/er825dch/1/)

Since you have only one active class to be set, you can alter the code like below,

```
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');

for (var t = 0; t < tabs.length; t++){
  tabs[t].addEventListener('click', function(){
   document.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active")
   this.classList.add('active');
  }, false);
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/er825dch/4/)

Comment: Thanks, that works. But what about more convenient decision, like in CSS - :not(this)?

Comment: @AleshaOleg I don't think that this could be done only by css.

Comment: I mean not use CSS, I just give you an example 'like' in CSS

Comment: @AleshaOleg You can use the optimized version like I updated recently.

Comment: yep, great. Thanks, for this

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/er825dch/3) is your fixed jsFiddle:

I just added function to access your cached tabs and remove the previous selected then apply new class on click.

```js
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');

function changeSelectedTab(tabEl) {
    for (var t = 0; t < tabs.length; t++) {
        tabs[t].className = 'tab';
    };
  
    tabEl.className += ' active';
}

for (var t = 0; t < tabs.length; t++) {
    tabs[t].addEventListener('click', function(){
        changeSelectedTab(this);
    }, false);
}
```

```css
.tabs {
    display: inline-block;
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        li {
            cursor: pointer;
            float: left;
            padding: 10px 40px;
            background: #FDFDFD;
            &.active {
                background: #8F95B0;
                color: #FFF;
                border-top-left-radius: 5px;
                border-top-right-radius: 5px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li class="tab active">Product Overview</li>
        <li class="tab">Specifications</li>
        <li class="tab">Related products</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```